# Git rebasing branch so commits and unstaged changes do not get deleted or lost

Tags: git, branch, git-merge, rebase

Lets say I have been working on a branch, made a bunch of changes some of which I committed some of which are still unstaged. Then someone else pushes something up to master. Then I am done and try to push my work to master. But there is a merge conflict, because the other person changed something in one of the files I was currently working on before pushing myself. What Git commands do I enter so that I get my branch updated with his changes, and my current work on top of that. So that I can merge. How do I do this without neither getting my commits lost nor my unstaged changes deleted? I destroy my project every time due to this. Simply which commands do I enter in which order to achieve this? I looked through the Git tutorial which said to git checkout branch, git rebase master. This ruined my project, again. Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try doing a `git stash` on your current branch.  This would essentially take a snapshot of your current stage and commit it somewhere in a safe place (and it would also do a separate commit for your working directory as well).

Then, pull in the latest changes:

```
git pull origin master
```

You might get merge conflicts when you do this, if you have new commits since you last synched with the remote `master` branch.

Finally, apply the stash via:

```
git stash apply
```

You also might get merge conflicts from this.  Now you should have the latest changes from your collaborator, and the stage should be as you left it.

Comment: Ok so I stash my work and not commit it until I pulled. After I pull I apply stash and commit. If i did a commit before stashing and theres a conflict what do I do? Stash the work in the commit and uncommit it?

Comment: I'm not sure what this follow up question is getting at, but if you make a commit, you should resolve the conflicts.  An unfinished commit should be viewed as a sort-of transient state; either don't do the commit, or complete it and resolve the conflicts.

Comment: Ok looks like I had a merge conflict that no amount or rebasing or stashing could solve. I just copy pasted the other guy's changes into my code... though it did not feel like the right way to do things